# run ls on the pipe output in shell script

Tags: bash, shell, sh

I have to do below operation in one script.

```
/etc/passwd file to display user home directory ownership:

ls -lLd /<usershomedirectory>
```

I can grep the home path as following, please help me with running the ls on the home path based on the user home path that is identified using single line script.

```
grep "" /etc/passwd | cut -f 6 -d :
```

### Updated

How to do it for some more ls

```
# ls -al /<usershomedirectory>/.login
# ls -al /<usershomedirectory>/.cschrc
# ls -al /<usershomedirectory>/.logout
# ls -al /<usershomedirectory>/.profile
# ls -al /<usershomedirectory>/.bash_profile
# ls -al /<usershomedirectory>/.bashrc
# ls -al /<usershomedirectory>/.bash_logout
# ls -al /<usershomedirectory>/.env
# ls -al /<usershomedirectory>/.dtprofile    
# ls -al /<usershomedirectory>/.dispatch
# ls -al /<usershomedirectory>/.emacs
# ls -al /<usershomedirectory>/.exrc
```

Comment: The expansion of `~username` is that user's home directory.

Comment: Maybe you should prefer `getent passwd` over reading the `passwd` file directly.

Answer (score 6):

You can use backticks/command output substitution:

```
ls -lLd "$(grep "^$username:" /etc/passwd | cut -f6 -d: )"
```

or piping to xargs:

```
grep "^$username:" /etc/passwd | cut -f 6 -d: | xargs -r ls -lLd
```

(I also added some more grep context to make sure the user matches exactly and supports blanks in file names)

The ~ expansion could be used with eval, not sure if thats a good idea:

```
eval "ls -lLd ~$username"
```

Answer (score 2):

As @EtanReisner commented, the usual way to do this would be:

```
ls -lLd ~user
```

However, if you must use parsing of `/etc/passwd` and substitution, I would recommend this particular recipe:

```
ls -lLd $(awk -v acct="user" -F: '$1 == acct { print $NF-1 }' /etc/passwd)
```

But there's quite a few ways, as the other answer(s) will demonstrate as well...